# Docker on Google Compute Engine - How do I mount host directory with correct permissions

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I'm using docker.io/solr:8.2.0 image on Google Compute Engine container instance, and have successfully got it running with a Mount path of /var/solr/data pointing to a Host path of /home/app/data

However, I'm having to do an extra step in the beginning to make /home/app/data writable by the container. I having to run in the host

```
sudo chown 8983:8983 /home/app -R
```

after that it works, /var/solr/data is mapped correctly and, on first run, even copies the files that are in the original /var/solr/data over to the host mount path

Is there a way to set this permission up in a start configuration so I can bypass this step?

Comment: Can you please add to your question the Dockerfile and the docker command used to run the docker container. If not possible to share the exact Dockerfile, just strip out what is confidential. Having a Dockerfile will make possible to try to reproduce your issue without doing guessings. Are you starting the container as a root user or non privileged user? To know run `id -u` and add to the question the output of it.

Comment: there's no Dockerfile, I'm using the Google Cloud Console to create a VM host that runs the container, within that screen there're sections for what container image to use and what the Volume mounts are

Comment: This use most likely an OS level configuration set-up. You could try using [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) on your virtual machines (VMs) to execute the 'chown' command. I hope this helps